# 3 types of playwright assertions with different results

Tags: typescript, playwright, assertion

I have the following lines of code. They are 3 different types of assertions that check for the same thing

```
await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true }).isVisible();
await expect (page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true }).isVisible());
expect(page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true })).toBeVisible();
```

The first assertion works perfectly fine.
The second one will display an error: expect: Property 'then' not found. If i remove "await" , the result is Error: locator.isVisible: Test ended.
The third one will display an error, that the item is hidden but in reality it is visible since the first assert works.

What exactly is wrong with 2nd and 3rd assertions ?

Answer (score 1):

there is a bit confusion about your code, let me try explain.

```
await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true }).isVisible();
```

This is not an assertion, it returns true/false for visability.

```
await expect (page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true }).isVisible());
```

You don't provided expectation condition, since the evaluation of expect returns true/false, you have to provide condition like: toBe()

```
expect(page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true })).toBeVisible();
```

This is actual expect with condition, but you did not provide await.

Here is more readable explanation with corrections:

```
// get element visibility.
const isVisible: boolean = await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true }).isVisible();
console.log(`Is Visible?: ${isVisible}`);

// assert element visibility is true
expect(await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', {exact: true}).isVisible()).toBe(true);

// do polling for expect element to be visible.
await expect(page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!', { exact: true })).toBeVisible();
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but for the 2nd line the result is as following: Expected: true
Received: {} and as for the 3rd line i did add the await but the result is the same, it still says it is hidden

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out, i have corrected the code. Had missing await in expect() for second example.

Comment: Good answer, but it might be worth mentioning that option 2 should almost never be used since it's not a web-first assertion, and option 1 isn't really used in testing. So option 3 is probably what OP wants.

Comment: if i do exactly your 2nd line, the result that comes up is false, but if i write "expect (await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!').isVisible());" this actually gives me the solution to what i was hoping to achieve. Can you explain this please ?

Comment: Option 3 still says that what i am looking for is hidden

Comment: `expect (await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!').isVisible());` - this is valid so far while `expect (await page.getByText('Thank you for your purchase!')).toBeVisible();` will display a false result. Can someone please explain this ?

Comment: @GetTok plz copy line 3 without changing it. The code in the comment is different.